# How can you display the number of rows in a mysql table that contain a null field using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm creating a webpage that displays in-coming and out-going calls to my business by displaying the calls after they are logged into a mysql table. I can tell which ones are still open by seeing if the 'close_dts' field is NULL. What i'd like to do is have a box in the top of the page that simply displays the number of open calls, which would be all the calls that have a NULL 'close_dts' field. I've seen several questions similar to this, but none of them show how to show results WITHOUT a certain field, or how to only display the number.

if it helps, here is the query i am using to display the calls in a table on the page.

```
SELECT FLOOR(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.create_dts) AS UNSIGNED) / 60) AS minutes, c.name, messages, m.high_priority_flag AS priority
FROM message m
JOIN client c ON m.client_id = c.client_id
WHERE m.update_dts IS NULL
ORDER BY priority DESC, minutes DESC;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What have you tried in PHP? Have you tried to connect to your database first? Then tried to execute the query after? Then handled the results after that?

Comment: use whatever your db library's "num_rows" function is, or do a `count(*)` query.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking, this will do:

```
SELECT count(*)
from message 
where close_dts is NULL;
```

Comment: That looks great, thanks! But how can i display the result? writing out $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query5); and then writing echo $result2 gives me an error.

Comment: ok, so i used this, but it only returns 1 everytime. what?                         <?php 
 if ($result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query5)) { 
  $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
  printf($row_cnt);
 }
 ?>

Comment: Because you're returning a count of the rows and not the count of  the query.